# Validation rule to check whether the status field on the opportunity is changed or not

Tags: picklist

I am trying to write a validation rule on the status of an opportunity object.
The scenario is like when the Opp Record type is " IN APP" the status should be read only.
No one can change the status.If they try to change it an error message should be displayed.

Any help in this is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

According to your scenario the following formula should work `RecordType.Name = 'IN APP' && ISCHANGED(Status)`.Where *Status* is a field name.

Comment: Include a NOT(ISNEW()) bit, just to be sure you can insert a record with that status and record type.

Comment: `ISCHANGED()` [always returns FALSE on a new record](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&siteLang=en_US#ISCHANGED), so not actually necessary to test for `ISNEW()` here.

Answer (score -1):

Try `isChanged(Status) && Status == 'In App'`. This will prevent any Status updates, so you need an "out" clause for whenever the Status can be updated again